# Linux : gsutil does not work in cron

Tags: linux, cron, gsutil

I'm trying to upload files to Google Cloud Storage using cron in Linux, but it fails.
I have also set path and configuration in my script file as :

```
PATH=/bin/gsutil/
export BOTO_CONFIG="/home/ashu/.boto"
# rest of script
```

But still nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed my pip install and used following link for installation :
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#specifications.

Also use of sudo should be avoided for path and export as it can lead to some issues.

```
PATH=$PATH:/root/gsutil/
export BOTO_CONFIG="/root/.boto"
# rest of script
```

Above code works well.

Answer (score 3):

And if you are using default installation provided by Google Cloud - Compute Engine, most probably gsutil is in /snap/bin

```
PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin
```

Comment: It is recommended to include quotes around `$PATH` e.g. `PATH="$PATH":/snap/bin`

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit safer to do

```
PATH="$PATH":/bin/gsutil/
```

so you don't kill access to the usual places like `/bin` and `/usr/bin` and etc.  You may not use them directly, but scripts you call might!

**update**: @ComputerDruid rightly points out that quotes keep spaces from causing trouble.

Comment: Safer still to do `PATH="$PATH":/bin/gsutil`, although it's quite rare to see a directory with spaces or other odd characters in `$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and I found that the simplest solution was to create a softlink between my gsutil installation and the system bin folder like this:

`sudo ln -s /snap/bin/gsutil /usr/bin/gsutil`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from modifying the PATH, as suggested by pjz, did you try to look at the actual output from gsutil / cron?

Which reason is given for the commend failing? In case you need to catch the output of gsutil,
you can redirect standard output and error (stdout and stderr) to a file, and save it there.

E.g. if you're using Bash, you could redirect the output to `gsutil_log.txt` by modifying your crontab as:

`*/1 * * * * /mypath/myscript.sh >> $HOME/gsutil_log.txt`

This will redirect `stdout` and `stderr` and append any output to `gsutil_log.txt` in `$HOME` for `myscript.sh` that is called every minute by cron.

If the output is helpful, that should advance you a bit with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the full path gsutil command to use in crontab

/root/gcloud/gsutil cp ...